# Laravel can't find a path 404

Tags: php, laravel, routes, http-status-codes

So my route:

```
Route::match(array('GET', 'POST'),'object/create', 'ObjectController@create');
```

And the ObjectController handler ->

```
class ObjectController extends Controller
{

public function create(Request $request){

        $fieldNames = array(
           .
           .
           .
        );

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
        $validator->setAttributeNames($fieldNames);

        if ($validator->fails()) 
        {
            return back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        }
        else
        {
         .
         .
         .

    }
```

When i try to acess to www.xxx.com/object/create it gives a 404 that can't find please any ideia?? I am new to laravel.
Thanks.

Comment: Do any other routes work? If not, ensure you have mod_rewrite enabled as per this part of the docs; https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/installation#pretty-urls. Also it should be obvious but make sure that route is in `web.php`...

Comment: Yes I have a object route for exemple and works

Comment: You maybe have a conflicting route above, e.g. `{slug}/create` which is being handled first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel, www.xxx.com/object/create will only work if you have defined the route in Routes/web.php, you can also give a namespace for the route using route-group
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Api'], function () {
check if the Namespace for your Route and Controller are same, and also check if there is any prefix for Your route.
if all the above are correct, Check app/provider/RouteServiceProvider.php

it Should look like this :

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * This namespace is applied to your controller routes.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

```
/**
 * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    //

    parent::boot();
}

/**
 * Define the routes for the application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function map()
{
    $this->mapApiRoutes();

    $this->mapWebRoutes();

    //
}

/**
 * Define the "web" routes for the application.
 *
 * These routes all receive session state, CSRF protection, etc.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function mapWebRoutes()
{
    Route::middleware('web')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
}

/**
 * Define the "api" routes for the application.
 *
 * These routes are typically stateless.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    Route::prefix('api')
         ->middleware('api')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
}
```

}

Comment: It is everything ok as you said, i dont no what is missing, it is driving with me crazy

Comment: Is it an API or web route

Comment: it is on web route

Comment: i have try change object/create in the routes to object.create and it finds! but of course the link also change

Comment: well problem solved insted of having object/create on the link it will have object-create